# Translate VBA syntax to Matlab for Activex control of Word document

Tags: matlab, vba, activex, office-interop

I am a newbie to using activex controls in matlab. Am trying to control a word document. I need help translating between VBA syntax and Matlab, I think. How would one code the following in matlab?

```
Sub macro()
With CaptionLabels("Table")
        .NumberStyle = wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic
        .IncludeChapterNumber = True
        .ChapterStyleLevel = 1
        .Separator = wdSeparatorHyphen
End With

Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Table", TitleAutoText:="", Title:="", _
        Position:=wdCaptionPositionAbove, ExcludeLabel:=0
End Sub
```

Thanks, I looked at the help and the source but I am still feeling dense.  I want to be able to control caption numbering and caption text in an automated report. Am using Tables and figures. I just can't quite get my head around how to code the addition of the captions.

The following code gets me part way there. But I don't have control over numbering style, etc,. I have tried to figure out the activex structure but I can't make sense of it. In particular, In particular the first bit the VB subroutine above.

```
% Start an ActiveX session with Word
hdlActiveX = actxserver('Word.Application');
hdlActiveX.Visible = true;
hdlWordDoc = invoke(hdlActiveX.Documents, 'Add');
hdlActiveX.Selection.InsertCaption('Table',captiontext);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some fiddling, I think I got it to work:

```sh
%# open Word
Word = actxserver('Word.Application');
Word.Visible = true;

%# create new document
doc = Word.Documents.Add;

%# set caption style for tables
t = Word.CaptionLabels.Item(2); %# 1:Figure, 2:Table, 3:Equation
t.NumberStyle = 0;              %# wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic
t.IncludeChapterNumber = false;
t.ChapterStyleLevel = 1;
t.Separator = 0;                %# wdSeparatorHyphen

%# insert table caption for current selection
Word.Selection.InsertCaption('Table', '', '', 0, false) %# wdCaptionPositionAbove

%# save document, then close
doc.SaveAs2( fullfile(pwd,'file.docx') )
doc.Close(false)

%# quit and cleanup
Word.Quit
Word.delete
```

Refer to the MSDN documentation to learn how to use this API. For example, the order of arguments of the [InsertCaption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertcaption.aspx) function used above.

Note that I had to set `IncludeChapterNumber` to false, otherwise Word was printing `"Error! No text of specified style in document"` inside the caption text...

Finally, to find out the integer values of the `wd*` enums, I am using the ILDASM tool to disassemble the Office Interop assemblies (as [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097358/enum-values-for-office-interop-via-dynamic-object/7097508#7097508) suggested). Simply dump the whole thing to text file, and search for the strings you are looking for.

[image: ildasm]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the help for `actxserver` and the source code for `xlsread.m` in the base MATLAB toolbox. If you're still stuck, then update your question with your progress.

**EDIT**:
You'll need to check the VBA help, but the first part ought to be possible via something like:

```
o = hdlWordDoc.CaptionLabels('Table');
o.NumberStyle = <some number corresponding to wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic>;
o.IncludeChapterNumber = true;
o.ChapterStyleLevel = 1;
o.Separator = <some number corresponding to wdSeparatorHyphen>;
```

In my experience, you have to get the values from the enumerations, such as wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic and wdSeparatorHyphen from a VBA script then hard-code them. You can try the following, but I don't think it works:

```
o.NumberStyle = 'wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic';
o.Separator = 'wdSeparatorHyphen';
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It was helpful. But I still am having touble navigating through the word document activex control within matlab. It seems like I should be able to code the first part of the VB routine as something like:

hdlActiveX.CaptionLabels.Tables.Numberstyle = wdCaptionNumberStyleArabic

I have tried navigating through the activex control in matlab but can't find my way. I apologize if this is unclear at all. Sometimes it's hard to ask a clear question about the things we struggle to understand.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of:
    o = hdlWordDoc.CaptionLabels('Table');
It returns an error. The following doesn't return an error but I can't crack the code as to where the controls I want are buried in the object. 
    o = hdlWordDoc.CaptionLabels;

Thanks for all the help. I need to switch projects now but will return to this as soon as I can.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the text values into the code, you can use the enum constants. This will help when a different language of Word is installed.

A list of the Enums can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word(enumerations)

So instead of:

`Word.Selection.InsertCaption('Table', '', '', 0, false) %# wdCaptionPositionAbove`

you can use this:

```
NET.addAssembly('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word')
Word.Selection.InsertCaption(...
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCaptionLabelID.wdCaptionTable.GetHashCode,...
     ' My custom table caption text', '', ...
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCaptionPosition.wdCaptionPositionAbove.GetHashCode, false)
```