# Add sparklines to excel with matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, com, activex, office-interop

With MATLAB I can start a COM server and programmatically write to an Excel workbook. However, I can't figure out a way to add sparklines (suggestions appreaciated):

```
% Open new workbook
excel         = actxserver('excel.application');
excel.visible = 1;
wrkbook       = excel.Workbooks.Add();
sheet         = wrkbook.Sheets.Item(1);

% Write some data
sheet.Range('B1:Z1').Value = rand(1,25);
```

Here is the problem:

```
% Add column sparklines to 'A1', type 'xlSparkColumn' and DataSource: 'B1:Z1'
sheet.Range('A1').SparklineGroups.Add('xlSparkColumn','B1:Z1')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_15.0_Object_Library.SparklineGroups/Add
Error: Object returned error code: 0x800A03EC
```

Close/cleanup

```
% Close without saving
wrkbook.Saved = 1;
wrkbook.Close
excel.Quit
delete(excel)
```

Reference to [SparklineGroup Object (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839170.aspx). I am on win7 64bit, R2013a and Excel 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
xlSparkColumn = 2;
sheet.Range('A1').SparklineGroups.Add(xlSparkColumn,'B1:Z1')
```

In the future, if you want to figure out the corresponding value for a certain constant/enum, use the IL DASM tool as shown in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7097508/97160) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589175/97160).

[image: ildasm]

---

#### EDIT

Ok it turns out that the enumeration [`xlSparkColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841146.aspx) was not the real issue here, you could either specify it as a string argument or pass the underlying integer value for the enum.

The problem as you mentioned in the comments is that you had the R1C1 [reference style](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/about-cell-and-range-references-HP005198323.aspx) set instead of the default A1 reference style, thus the range specified in your call was not valid in that format.

Either of these will work:

```
excel.ReferenceStyle = 'xlR1C1';
sheet.Range('A1').SparklineGroups.Add('xlSparkColumn','R1C2:R1C26')

excel.ReferenceStyle = 'xlA1';
sheet.Range('A2').SparklineGroups.Add('xlSparkColumn','B1:Z1')
```

Comment: Figured it out: apparently the R1C1 reference style was interfering (File > Options > Fromulas > Working with formulas, then untick R1C1 reference style). The question is why? Now it works even with string type.

Comment: Your solutions threw the same error. I tried by chance to uncheck the R1C1 style, which solved the issue both for your solution and mine, i.e. with 'xlSparkColumn'. Therefore, the problem was the reference style, rather than the enumeration.

Comment: ok I can confirm that.. Perhaps you can include the following line at the beginning to make sure the [R1C1 reference style](http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/the-beauty-of-the-r1c1-reference-style/) is not used: `excel.ReferenceStyle = 'xlA1'`. Maybe someone else can explain why is that required here.. I'm also not sure about string vs integer values, I thought only integer values worked..