# Color highpoint/lowpoint in sparkline excel plot through MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, com, activex

In reference to my previous question ([add sparklines to excel with matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996850/)), I can manage to create sparklines, but I can't figure out how to color the highpoint/lowpoint in green/red. I tried:

```
% Open new workbook
excel         = actxserver('excel.application');
excel.visible = 1;
wrkbook       = excel.Workbooks.Add();
sheet         = wrkbook.Sheets.Item(1);

% Write some data
sheet.Range('B1:Z1').Value = rand(1,25);

% Add column sparklines to 'A1', type 'xlSparkColumn' and DataSource: 'B1:Z1'
excel.ReferenceStyle = 'xlA1';
s = sheet.Range('A1').SparklineGroups.Add('xlSparkColumn','B1:Z1');

% Color
s.Point.Highpoint.Color.Color = 4697456;
s.Point.Lowpoint.Color.Color  = 255;
```

Also see this reference on [setting custom cell background color](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-QLD4K/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
% set highpoint color to red (color format is BGR)
s.Points.Highpoint.Color.Color = hex2dec('0000FF');

% make it visible
s.Points.Highpoint.Visible = true;
```

[image: sparklines]

Comment: Thanks for the `.Visible = true`. I am sorta in a rush, but once I have time I'll definitely check your previous link to the tool.